# Group by in Django?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have the next structure in my django app:

```
class Telefono(models.Model):
    tipo = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    lada = models.IntegerField()
    numero = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return (self.tipo +" - (" +str(self.lada)+")"+str(self.numero))



class Persona(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    apellidoPaterno = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    apellidoMaterno = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    rfc = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    ubicacion = models.OneToOneField(Ubicacion)
    telefonos = models.ManyToManyField(Telefono)
```

The problem is: I need a single "telefono" to show in my datagrid.. so I built the next query in MYSQL:

```
select p.nombre,tf.numero from persona as p join persona_telefonos AS t ON t.persona_id=p.id join telefono As tf ON t.telefono_id=tf.id group by p.id
```

And actually gives this result:

```
"nombre"    "numero"
"MiKchorro123213"   "5345234523"
```

But in django I have this query:

```
Cliente.objects.filter().values("id","nombre","telefonos__numero", "ubicacion__direccion")
```

And I get two results.. one for each ("telefono") object in the many to many relationship..

How can I do a group by function in django?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer documentation : [Raw Query, Filterings, Group_by](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#topics-db-sql)

example:

```
    query = Cliente.objects.all().query
    query.group_by = ['field_name']
    results = QuerySet(query=query, model=Model_name)
```